# Maximize in ckeditor covers save on data entry screen

Tags: ckeditor, maximize

I have a data entry screen that has a CKEditor window.  The users click the maximize button that covers my application toolbar.  The issue is that they get confused and click the X in the corner and close the window.  is there a way to keep a toolbar when maximizing?

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this code on javascript tag

`<script>
CKEDITOR.config.height = '800';
</script>`